# What to do with good questions on Help and Improvement review type

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, help-improvement

I just got to review 'Help and Improvement'.

I know that the posts there comes from the Triage review queue, when a reviewer clicks "Requires Editing".

But sometimes I see some questions which are good enough, and there is no need to edit them.

Perhaps the reviewer didn't review correctly on the Triage reviews.

Shouldn't there be a button saying "This question doesn't require editing". Or is that the purpose of the skip button?

Comment: I would just click "Skip".